# Get rows from a powershell output

Tags: powershell

I've got an output like this:

```
Schema:
  Column Name                   Localized Name                Type    MaxLength
  ----------------------------  ----------------------------  ------  ---------
  RequestID                     Issued Request ID             Long    4 -- Indexed

Maximum Row Index: 0

0 Rows
   0 Row Properties, Total Size = 0, Max Size = 0, Ave Size = 0
   0 Request Attributes, Total Size = 0, Max Size = 0, Ave Size = 0
   0 Certificate Extensions, Total Size = 0, Max Size = 0, Ave Size = 0
   0 Total Fields, Total Size = 0, Max Size = 0, Ave Size = 0
CertUtil: -view command completed successfully.
```

I need to do something if Rows are equal to 0 and somethingelse if Rows are distinct to 0

```
If Rows = 0 then
    Write-host "do something"
Else
    Write-host "Do nothing"
```

How could I get the number of rows into a variable?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using chained -match and -replace operators with your test data:

```
$text = (@'
Schema:
  Column Name                   Localized Name                Type    MaxLength
  ----------------------------  ----------------------------  ------  ---------
  RequestID                     Issued Request ID             Long    4 -- Indexed

Maximum Row Index: 0

0 Rows
   0 Row Properties, Total Size = 0, Max Size = 0, Ave Size = 0
   0 Request Attributes, Total Size = 0, Max Size = 0, Ave Size = 0
   0 Certificate Extensions, Total Size = 0, Max Size = 0, Ave Size = 0
   0 Total Fields, Total Size = 0, Max Size = 0, Ave Size = 0
CertUtil: -view command completed successfully.
'@).split("`n") |
foreach {$_.trim()} 


$Rows = $text -match '^\d+ Rows\s*$' -replace '^(\d+).+','$1'
$Rows

0
```